# Converting a function to MySQLi in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Hi there i'm trying to convert the following function into MySQLi. I have done some but I can't figure out the rest. Can you help me?

```
function user_exists($username) {
$connect = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "password", "table") or die("Sorry, we are experiencing technical difficulties. Please try again later.");

$username = sanitize($username);
$query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'");
return (mysql_result($query, 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: `return mysqli_result($query, 0) == 1;`

Comment: @JohnBupit I just edited it and got this result "Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_result()"

Comment: Sorry, my bad. My point was just to eliminate the ternary operator. 
`mysqli_result` is indeed not a function. You could make your own, or you could use `mysqli_fetch_assoc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing mysqli and mysql functions.you mea to use `mysqli_result`?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you are asking

Comment: Basically can you tell me what I need to change? So edit my code so I can update it. Cheers

Comment: There is no `mysqli_result` function.